# Comparing the definitions of perfect complexes on algebraic stacks and schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be an algebraic stack. In [Perfect complexes on algebraic stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1887) (4.1) a *perfect complex* $P \in \mathsf{D}_{\mathrm qc}(X)$ is defined to be a complex such that, for any smooth morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(A) \to X$ (where $A$ is a commutative ring), the complex $\mathbf{R}\Gamma(X,P_{|\operatorname{Spec}(A)})$ is a perfect complex of $A$-modules.

On the other hand, if $X$ is just a scheme, then a complex $P \in \mathsf{D}_{\mathrm qc}(X)$ is called perfect if it is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of locally free sheaves of finite rank.

Question: if $X$ is a scheme, how can I prove that the two definitions agree? Is there a reference with a proof of this fact?

Comment: Thomason-Trobaugh?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood, but you seem to be asking why the property of being a perfect complex is preserved by smooth pullbacks. Given a bounded complex of vector bundles on a scheme $X$, their pullback under any smooth affine map $Spec(A) \to X$ is a bounded complex of locally free $A$-modules. On the other hand, the property of being a bounded complex of vector bundles can be checked locally (even in the Zariski topology). Thus the two definitions agree.

Comment: I think at least part of the OP's question comes from the fact that the OP has the wrong definition of perfect complex in general. In general (as Leo Alonso says), a perfect complex is only \emph{locally} (in say the Zariski topology) quasi-iso. to a bounded complex of vector bundles. For "nice" schemes, it's a theorem (probably in Thomason-Trobaugh), that one gets a global quasi-iso.  I learned about it from remark 1.7 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302304v2.pdf, which should give suitable references.

Answer (score 5):

A perfect complex is one that it is locally quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of locally free sheaves of finite rank. On schemes you use Zariski topology, but it makes sense verbatim on any **ringed topos**. On stacks, you may use one of the *big* topologies with all of their drawbacks (and some advantages like obvious functoriality) or a small one, like the *lisse-étale* site. In this case, the translation of the definition given above is more or less what you say. That on schemes both notions agree is a consequence of flat descent for quasi-coherent sheaves.